# How to display nano seconds in excel while export from oracle

Tags: excel, oracle, csv, excel-2007, export-to-csv

i have table in oracle
below column

2019-06-01 01:21:14.000173

2019-06-01 01:23:14.000323

2019-06-01 01:25:14.000443

2019-06-01 01:27:14.000594

2019-06-01 01:29:14.000653

2019-06-01 01:31:14.000813

but while export to csv getting below

01-06-2019 01:21:14.000

01-06-2019 01:23:14.000

01-06-2019 01:25:14.000

01-06-2019 01:27:14.001

01-06-2019 01:29:14.001

01-06-2019 01:31:14.001

unable to export column with nano seconds

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your timestamp values to string

```
 to_char(systimestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF6')
```

```
Result:
------
2019-06-04 12:40:31.080000
```